# CSS: Absolutely positioning each character while still remaining selectable/searchable

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to absolutely place each character in a paragraph, but while doing so I still need the text to be selectable.

If I use `position:absolute` in a span around each character I can correctly place every character wherever I want on the page. However, in this case the user is unable to correctly select the text because spaces and paragraphs disappear when selected, e.g. the user will get `Thisisatest.` instead of `This is a test.` when selecting the and copying the text. The main problem with this is that the user will be unable to search on the page.

On the other hand if I use `position:relative` then I can place the characters still anywhere and it will select and search correctly, but the problem is that a leading is added after each character. E.g. the browser's cursor position for where to render the next glyph is adjusted (pushed forward) by that font's glyhph's leading. I can't adjust for this because I don't know what the leading is. The leading can be adjusted to be larger or smaller with `letter-spacing`, but I don't seem to be able to eradicate it altogether with that property. The leading is different on each character and I don't know what these values are, especially because it's using custom fonts.

The solution would be either:

1. I use relative positioning but somehow tell the CSS to use absolutely zero letter-spacing and zero line-spacing (meaning if I did not position each character myself they'd all be on top of one another.)
2. Or I use absolute positioning but CSS actually considers it one paragraph of text instead of a non-stream of individually placed characters, and so allows for proper selection and searching.

Any ideas?

Here are some of the tests I've been trying:
https://jsfiddle.net/8hen4483/

You can see from the test that the relative positioned text always moves forward even if the `left:0px` is set, and the absolute positioned text does not but if you select it you lose the space in `Test !`

Comment: I think you need to put the spaces inside spans too. But a little piece of the code that doesn't fully work would be helpful, so we can see and test and improve on it.

Comment: I only have my tests, which I've added the link for. Thanks.

Comment: The selection part can be solved with `&nbsp;` (not required in IE BTW), but that doesn't help search. Why are you doing this in the first place?